# Hibernate: set condition to multiple level childs

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a question about hibernate query. I am using hiberate 5.3.10.

First of all, I have domain Parent.java, ParentAlert.java and ParentAlertDetail.java like follow:

Parent:

```
public class Parent {
private String parentId;
private List<ParentAlert> parentAlerts;

@Id 
@Column(name = "Parent_id", length = 12)
public String getParentId() {
    return parentId;
}

public void setParentId(String parentId) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
}

@OneToMany(
        targetEntity = ParentAlert.class, 
        mappedBy = "parentAlert", 
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public List<ParentAlert> getParentAlerts() {
    return parentAlerts;
}

public void setParentAlerts(List<ParentAlert> parentAlerts) {
    this.parentAlerts = parentAlerts;
}}
```

ParentAlert:

```
public class ParentAlert {

private String parentAlertID;
private Parent parent;
private Collection<ParentAlertDetail> parentAlertDetails;
private String status;

@Id
@Column(name = "Parent_Alert_ID", length = 12)
@NotEmpty
public String getParentAlertID() {
    return parentAlertID;
}

public void setParentAlertID(String parentAlertID) {
    this.parentAlertID = parentAlertID;
}

@OneToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "Parent_id")
public Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

@OneToMany(targetEntity = ParentAlertDetail.class, mappedBy = "id.parentAlert", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL })
public Collection<ParentAlertDetail> getParentAlertDetails() {
    return parentAlertDetails;
}

public void setParentAlertDetails(Collection<ParentAlertDetail> parentAlertDetails) {
    this.parentAlertDetails = parentAlertDetails;
}

@Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 1)
public String getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}}
```

ParentAlertDetail

```
public class ParentAlertDetail{

private ParentAlertDetailID id;
private String desc;
private String status;

@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides(value = { @AttributeOverride(name = "parentAlert", column = @Column(name = "Parent_Alert_Id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "parentAlertDetailId", column = @Column(name = "Parent_Alert_Detail_id")) })
public ParentAlertDetailID getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(ParentAlertDetailID id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "desc", length = 100)
public String getDesc() {
    return this.desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

@Column(name = "Status", length = 1)
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}}
```

ParentAlertDetailID

```
public class ParentAlertDetailID{                                                                                                  

private Integer parentAlertDetailId;                                                                                                                          
private ParentAlert parentAlert;                                                                                                                           

@Column(name = "Parent_Alert_Detail_id")                                                                                                                       
@NotEmpty                                                                                                                                                      
public Integer getParentAlertDetailId() {                                                                                                                     
    return parentAlertDetailId;                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                              

public void setParentAlertDetailId(Integer parentAlertDetailId) {                                                                                            
    this.parentAlertDetailId = parentAlertDetailId;                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                                              

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = ParentAlert.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)                                                                                        
@JoinColumn(name = "Parent_Alert_ID", nullable = true)                                                                                                         
public ParentAlert getParentAlert() {                                                                                                                      
    return parentAlert;                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                              

public void setParentAlert(ParentAlert parentAlert) {                                                                                                     
    this.parentAlert = parentAlert;                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                                           }
```

I would like to filter the parentAlert.status = 'A' and parentAlertDetail.status = 'A'.

The query is

```
    String sql = "SELECT distinct parent FROM Parent parent" 
                     + " LEFT OUTER JOIN fetch parent.parentAlerts patientAlert"
                     + " LEFT OUTER JOIN patientAlert.patientAlertDetails patientAlertDetail"
                     + " WHERE (patientAlert.status ='A' or patientAlert.status is null) "
                     + " and (patientAlertDetail.status ='A' or patientAlertDetail.status is null)";

        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql);
                 List<Parent> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

However, I found that the records under PatientAlertDetail cannot be filter (mean that patientAlertDetail.status = 'I' records selected also)

May I ask anything wrong in my query or domain?

Also, is it possible to fetch all tables in parent domain without using fetch in the query? This is because I have more than one child domain in Parent (e.g. ParentContact etc)

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to filter child collections with a query

Comment: @SimonMartinelli what can I do if I want to filter the child collections??

Comment: No using Entities. Please tell us your use case

Comment: My use case is get all information under Parent but need to filter the patientAlertDetail.status ='A'

Comment: Actually i need to fetch multiple child under Parent. If it possible the fetch child without declare fetch in the query. It is because some articles mentioned that only one fetch in one query

Comment: You have to do mulitple queries to achieve your goal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205522/discussion-between-leonlai-and-simon-martinelli).